# Why is my TPMS light solid after replacing all 4 sensors, reprogramming and verifying proper psi in live data?

Tags: toyota, camry, tire-pressure-monitoring-system

2009 Toyota Camry SE V6. I replaced all 4 sensors after 1 died. I reprogrammed using my Autel MK808BT for the new sensors ID's AND verified each tire is reporting ~34 psi in the live data. However, the TPMS light on the dash remains solid never flashing. I'm looking for ideas as to what I'm missing. There are no trouble codes within the TPMS section of the Autel diagnostics. I do have C0210 and C0215, which are left and right rear speed sensor codes, and a sunroof code, but that's a whole different section of diagnostic. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure the new sensors are compatible with your vehicle? Did you check the spare tire's sensor?

Comment: Yes, they are. No sensor in the spare.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a drive interval that prevents the light from going back off until the minimum drives or drive time. I'm not sure which. But the light just eventually went off after a couple days and around 5 or 6 drive cycles.